# using php to fetch a record based on "_id" from mongo db

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to fetch a record from mongo db using php. I am trying to use _id field in the mongo collection to access the record. But i am unable to fetch the corresponding record and i am only getting null. This is the code i am using.

```
$db =  $this->Generalmodel->connect();
$collection = $db->listing;
$cursor = $collection->findOne(array("_id"=>$id));
var_dump($cursor);
```

I also tried it with the following and is of no use too

```
$collection = $db->listing;
$cursor = $collection->find(array( '$and' => array( array('_id' => $id), array('blocked' => "0"))));
foreach ($cursor as $obj)
var_dump($obj)
```

Am i missing something here?

Comment: it's the value i fetch from my session. Basically it is the _id generated by mongo, from a list of entities i am using this to select detailed info about one single entity

Comment: I mean, what type is it? Actual ObjectId, or did it get converted to string?

Comment: its a string. While storing it in session, it gets stored as a string

Comment: Well, then convert it back to ObjectId. That's why record can not be found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

array('_id' => new MongoID($id))

Comment: found this after @Sergei Tulentsev said that